# Why does one k8s cluster allow running entrypoint scripts without execution permission bit and another one doesn't?

Tags: kubernetes, permissions

I'm trying to understand why my deployment fails on 1.23+ (aws) but runs fine on 1.24 (gcp). I expect it to fail on both and I need tips in finding out why. Is it something that k8s changed across versions or is it about the underlying container engine?

Consider the following output from exec-ing into a sleeping (`tail -f /dev/null`) container:

```
/data $ ps -ef
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 6379      0:00 {sleeper} /bin/sh /scripts/sleeper
    7 6379      0:00 tail -f /dev/null
    8 6379      0:00 sh -c clear; (bash || ash || sh)
   15 6379      0:00 ash
   16 6379      0:00 ps -ef
/data $ ls -l /scripts/..data/sleeper 
-rwxr-----    1 root     6379            27 Apr  6 15:31 /scripts/..data/sleeper
/data $ id
uid=6379 gid=0(root) groups=6379
```

Notice how the script has no group (nor other/world) execution rights but k8s 1.24 on GCP runs it fine with a non-root user when only root is allowed to execute it. Whereas k8s 1.23+ on AWS throws the following container error:

```
Reason: ContainerCannotRun - exit code: 126
```

The full error event is:

```
Error: failed to start container "alpine-sleeper": 
Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: 
OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: 
unable to start container process: 
exec /scripts/sleeper: permission denied: unknown
```

The corresponding version outputs are as follows:

```
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"23+", GitVersion:"v1.23.16-eks-48e63af", GitCommit:"e6332a8a3feb9e0fe3db851878f88cb73d49dd7a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-01-24T19:18:15Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

and

```
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"24", GitVersion:"v1.24.10-gke.2300", GitCommit:"1d7ae0799b40b0cd95502e3a5e698db62572e341", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2023-02-22T09:28:49Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.6 X:boringcrypto", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Any feedback is welcome.

*Update 1:* Turns out that AWS is using docker runtime whereas GCP: containerd. Is that a known thing with docker that it allows executing a file with a group user without group execution bit?

Comment: This does not seem to be related to Kubernetes, but to the container runtime in use.

Comment: Thanks but they both use containerd afaik. What can I check in that regard? Just version?

Comment: Correction: they're not both containerd. I've updated my question with more info.